# Wifi not always working dual boot Ubuntu 20.04, Win10

Tags: dual-boot, wireless

Dell 7480, new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 along side Win10 and it seems to work except for the Wifi in Ubuntu. Secure boot and Fast startup are disabled.

I thought it was only problem when I did a 'restart' instead of a 'shutdown' from Windows (where Wifi always works), but that isn't the case anymore. It worked for a while though, so I've used Wifi in Ubuntu many times. It also worked fine running live from the USB. If I have a network cable plugged in when I boot Ubuntu then remove it, the Wifi works.

I think I saw something about this type of problem somewhere but can't find it anymore. I ran these commands/diagnostics:

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ef000000-ef001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: e4:b9:7a:11:2f:78
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.0.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 memory:ef200000-ef21ffff
```

lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```